# Array con Strings en C++

Tags: c++, array, string

¿Cómo se haría para realizar un array que contenga varios String en cada posición en c++?, me encuentro con un inconveniente, no tengo muy claro cómo se establece un array con Strings y cómo se haría para acceder a cada String y cómo se accedería a cada letra de uno de los String. El concepto sería el siguiente:

```
words=[10]={"Londres","Paris","Dublin","Madrid","Roma","Atenas","Lisboa","Berlin","Amsterdam","Cardiff"}
```

Mi intensión es por medio de una variable que contenga un numero aleatorio que será el puntero que indicará una posición del array **words**, por lo que necesitaría conocer la longitud del array, pero tengo entendido que la siguiente expresión no es útil en este caso:

```
strlen(words)
```

y una vez se seleccionó uno de los string del array, necesito recorrer los caracteres del string seleccionado para luego modificar dichos caracteres.¿Cómo se programaría?, no tengo muy claro cómo plantearlo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ¿Cómo se haría para realizar un array que contenga varios String en cada posición en c++?

El `namespace std` te provee el tipo `string`. Puedes crear arrays tipo `string` e inicializarlos con strings.

```
std::string arr[3] = {"Mango","Banano","Limon"};
```

> cómo se haría para acceder a cada String

Es un array normal, se pueden realizar iteraciones sobre los elementos de este y acceder por indices a los elementos de este.

*Ciclo `for` que muestra por pantalla cada elementos del array*

```
for (std::string i: arr) {
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

*`cout` de un indice del array*

```
std::cout << arr[0];
```

> cómo se accedería a cada letra de uno de los String.

Realmente, los strings son arrays de caracteres, es decir los strings tiene las mismas propiedades que tendría un array tipo `char`. Por lo tanto puedes acceder a cada letra por su indice o por iteraciones `for ... in` o `for`.

*`cout` de la primera letra del ultimo elemento del array*

```
std::cout << arr[2][0];
```

> pero tengo entendido que la siguiente expresión no es útil en este caso:

```
strlen(words)
```

El prototipo de `strlen()` según [esta documentación](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strlen) es

```
strlen(const char* start)
```

Un apuntador `char` no es lo mismo que un `string`. Si intentas usar un `strlen()` con un elemento tipo `string` obtienes un error.

```
error: cannot convert 'std::__cxx11::string' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>'} to 'const char*'
```

De cualquier manera el ejemplo que pones no sería válido, ya que `words` es un array.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: En el bucle `for (std::string i: arr)` estás copiando cada cadena en `i`, eso es muy costoso a nivel de proceso. Usa referencias (para evitar copias) constantes (porque no hay intención de modificar nada): `for (const std::string &i: arr)`, puedes incluso ahorrar texto usando deducción de tipos: `for (const auto &i: arr)`.

Comment: No sabía eso, gracias por la observación.